# Convert a 17 digit unix timestamp into something matplotlib understands

Tags: json, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

The code posted below works & prints out a list of lists that contain a wierd 17 digit list that is a timestamp e.g., 20170418030000000

```
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from matplotlib import style

    import urllib
    import json
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import datetime as dt
    import time
    import pandas as pd  # data manipulation
    import numpy as np  # number crunching

    dataLink ='http://api.huobi.com/staticmarket/btc_kline_015_json.js'
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(dataLink)
    data = data.read().decode("utf-8")
    data = json.loads(data)
    data = [data]  
    #ts=data[0][0][0]

    for sublist in data[0]:
        ts=sublist[:1]
        openp=sublist[1:2]
        highp = sublist[2:3]
        lowp = sublist[3:4]
        closep = sublist[4:5]
        vol = sublist[5:6]
        print(ts)
        print(openp)
        print(highp)
        print(lowp)
        print(closep)
        print(vol)
        print()
```

My question is, "how can I convert the timestamp into something that matplotlib will allow me to graph along the x-axis?" I've edited out most of the matplotlib stuff. I'll do that bit after I've sorted this out...

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Pandas module:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

dataLink ='http://api.huobi.com/staticmarket/btc_kline_015_json.js'
r = requests.get(dataLink)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(r.json())
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0].str[:-3], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print(df)
df.set_index(0).plot()
plt.show()
```

Result:

```
In [37]: print(df)
                      0        1        2        3        4        5
0   2017-04-15 03:00:00  7069.83  7072.40  7040.08  7040.08   2.3042
1   2017-04-15 03:15:00  7069.34  7069.52  7030.48  7069.52   0.5011
2   2017-04-15 03:30:00  7068.65  7068.65  7068.65  7068.65   0.0177
3   2017-04-15 03:45:00  7068.65  7068.65  7068.65  7068.65   0.0000
4   2017-04-15 04:00:00  7065.94  7065.94  7065.94  7065.94   0.0023
5   2017-04-15 04:15:00  7055.60  7055.60  7055.60  7055.60   0.0001
6   2017-04-15 04:30:00  7055.54  7071.63  7030.07  7032.17   3.9101
7   2017-04-15 04:45:00  7040.03  7040.43  7032.20  7040.43   3.2215
8   2017-04-15 05:00:00  7032.48  7067.87  7032.20  7066.97   2.4587
9   2017-04-15 05:15:00  7039.08  7064.18  7038.73  7038.73   0.2955
..                  ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
290 2017-04-18 03:30:00  7088.40  7088.40  7088.40  7088.40   0.0379
291 2017-04-18 03:45:00  7101.01  7102.85  7101.01  7102.85   0.4247
292 2017-04-18 04:00:00  7099.71  7108.00  7089.52  7108.00  15.6556
293 2017-04-18 04:15:00  7108.00  7108.00  7108.00  7108.00   0.0000
294 2017-04-18 04:30:00  7090.58  7090.58  7086.50  7086.50   0.5679
295 2017-04-18 04:45:00  7100.00  7100.00  7086.50  7086.50  10.7334
296 2017-04-18 05:00:00  7098.26  7098.26  7084.61  7084.61   2.1534
297 2017-04-18 05:15:00  7097.70  7097.70  7084.61  7084.61   0.6402
298 2017-04-18 05:30:00  7085.00  7085.00  7085.00  7085.00   0.1674
299 2017-04-18 05:45:00  7085.00  7085.00  7085.00  7085.00   0.0000

[300 rows x 6 columns]
```

[image]